# How do I replace the AoT OS with Oreo/Kitkat/lollipop or similar full Android OS

Tags: android-things, android-things-console

How do I replace the AoT OS with Oreo/Kitkat/lollipop or similar full Android OS on the NXP imx7 Android of Things kit.

Cheers

Rob

Comment: You can build Android from [sources](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building) but it's too broad question.

Comment: My 11 year old son was given the pico NXP Imx7 kit for his birthday, he has built it and he has the app on his phone, we have it connected to the home wifi and updated the Android things OS.  Beyond that my son cant use it to "play with". MY intention was to replace the Android things OS with a standard Android inage so it seems like a phone/tablet to my son so he can install apps from Google Store and watch youtube etc...is that possibe?

Comment: Yes, its possible (Android can be installed on every board where Linux can run): you can build it from [sources](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building) and [flash](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/flashing-updating)  binaries to board. But its not a trivial task. Take a look at [this link](https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/run-time-software/i.mx-developer-resources/android-os-for-i.mx-applications-processors:IMXANDROID).